# Prevent toast notification from appearing twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to show a toast notification when a service worker updates but the toast notification shows up two times. It seems that its because of the useEffect hook but am not being able to understand how to fix the problem.

**In App.js**

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import * as serviceWorker from "../serviceWorker";
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";

const App = () => {
    const [newVersionAvailable, setNewVersionAvailable] = useState(false);
    const [waitingWorker, setWaitingWorker] = useState({});
    const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

    const onServiceWorkerUpdate = (registration) => {
        setNewVersionAvailable(true);
        setWaitingWorker(registration && registration.waiting);
    }

    const updateServiceWorker = () => {
        if(waitingWorker) {
            waitingWorker.addEventListener("statechange", event => {
                if(event.target.state === "activated") {
                    setNewVersionAvailable(false);
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            })

            waitingWorker.postMessage({ type: "SKIP_WAITING" });
        }
    }

    const updateAction = () => {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Button
                    className="snackbar-button"
                    size="small"
                    onClick={ updateServiceWorker }
                >
                    { "Update" }
                </Button>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        serviceWorker.register({ onUpdate: onServiceWorkerUpdate });

        if(newVersionAvailable) {
            enqueueSnackbar("New Update Available!", {
                persist: true,
                anchorOrigin: {
                    vertical: "bottom",
                    horizontal: "center",
                },
                action: updateAction,
            })
        }
    })

    return (...);
```

Comment: No dependency array == trigger effect every time, what do you want to trigger the toast? Just `newVersionAvailable`?

Comment: I want to trigger the toast when a new service worker is available. So when it is available I set the `newVersionAvailable` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know from the code you've posted but what (if any) props do you have ? As it stands your `useEffect` will respond to every prop change. Perhaps you need to add a dependency array and only have `useEffect` trigger on certain prop changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
        serviceWorker.register({ onUpdate: onServiceWorkerUpdate });

        if(newVersionAvailable) {
            enqueueSnackbar("New Update Available!", {
                persist: true,
                anchorOrigin: {
                    vertical: "bottom",
                    horizontal: "center",
                },
                action: updateAction,
            })
        }
    }, [prop_whose_change_you_want_to_trigger_this_useEffect])
```

Comment: There are no props. I tried adding the deps array with `newVersionAvailable` but it still showed me with two toast notification. Although the first notification's button didnt work while the second did work.

Comment: Edit : From reading your response above you could just set the dependency array to [serviceWorker] if that's the only thing which you want to use to trigger the useEffect.

Comment: serviceWorker is the script and not any value.

Answer (score 0):

Add `newVersionAvailable` to the effect's dependency array, then set back to false once the toast it fired off so it isn't triggered again.

```
useEffect(() => {
    serviceWorker.register({ onUpdate: onServiceWorkerUpdate });

    if(newVersionAvailable) {
        enqueueSnackbar("New Update Available!", {
            persist: true,
            anchorOrigin: {
                vertical: "bottom",
                horizontal: "center",
            },
            action: updateAction,
        });
        setNewVersionAvailable(false);
    }
}, [newVersionAvailable])
```

Comment: My scenario is something like this: Refresh the page, service worker changes are picked up and two toast are displayed. Both have an action button but the first toast's action button doesnt work whereas the second one works.

Comment: @Ayan If you can, can you describe at greater detail what the flow of the component is, i.e. the sequence of events? I have a hunch the effect is doing the reverse of what you want it to do. You may need two separate effects, i.e. one to run and check service workers when the component mounts, and another to trigger the toast when ready. Explaining in more detail what your flow is/should be may help us answer.

Comment: the sequence is simple. The app is a CRA. Its basically barebones. I have modified the App.js file to include the service worked and put in it a callback `onUpdate` as the config. The app.js has some route definitions in the render and the rest of the code is as above in the question.